# .NET Core Database Connection Errors with Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

Locally, my code works fine. However, when I try to publish to Azure, I get the following error:

```
'One or more errors occurred. (Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See inner exception for the most recent failure.)'
```

The error occurs on the following line in my `Startup.cs` file, used to seed the Admin user:

```
ApplicationIdentityDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration).Wait();
```

This calls the static method:

```
public static async Task CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            string username = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Name"];
            string email = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Email"];
            string password = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Password"];
            string role = configuration["Data:AdminUser:Role"];

            if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) == null)
            {
                if(await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                }

                AppUser user = new AppUser
                {
                    UserName = username,
                    Email = email
                };

                IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
                }
            }
        }
```

The `Name`, `Email`, `Password`, and `Role` properties are in my `appSettings.json` file and appear to be set correctly. I've checked my connection string and firewall settings and everything seems ok.

If I comment out the line causing the error, publish, and then try to register a user in the database from the website, I get the following error:

`SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.`

I'm using Identity to manage users and previous applications would create the necessary tables if they didn't exist. These apps were not .NET Core apps though...is the strategy to publish .NET Core apps to Azure fundamentally different?

Comment: The error message is pretty generic and tells you to look at the inner exception. Did you take a look at that?

Comment: @LewsTherin it's a failure to respond comm fail. I've checked the credentials on the connection string and the user/password seem correct and the Azure portal is indicating that the database is responsive